# Optimize Python Pandas code

Tags: python, pandas, similarity

```
Scorelife_disct={'scorelife41': ['c', 'hindi', 'sql', 'scala', 'love'],
 'scorelife42': ['c', 'sql', 'english', 'Cat', 'html', 'cPlus', 'love'],
 'scorelife43': ['c', 'Cat', 'friend', 'love']}

User_life_disct ={'scorelifeLife1': ['c', 'hindi', 'python', 'scala', 'graphics'],
 'scorelifeLife10': ['c', 'hindi', 'perl'],
 'scorelifeLife11': ['hindi', 'perl', 'spark']}

import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)

from __future__ import division
for userid in Scorelife_disct:
    #print userid
    for life_disct in User_life_disct:

        u1= Scorelife_disct[userid]
        u2= User_life_disct[life_disct]
        k1=len(set(u1)&set(u2))/len(set(u1)|set(u2))
        #print life_disct
        #print k1

        d[userid][life_disct] = k1
        print d
dict(d)
```

Output:

```
{' scorelife41': {' scorelifeLife1': 0.42857142857142855,
  ' scorelifeLife10': 0.3333333333333333,
  ' scorelifeLife11': 0.14285714285714285 }}
```

I am using two python dictionary with Jaccard similarity between each list of dictionary, but my program is taking too much time for huge amount of data. How do I reduce the time complexity problem (although the output is correct) so that it works without taking not much time?

Comment: How is this using Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built-in profilers to see where your code is bottlenecking: [How can you profile a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-script).

Given the snippet in the question, the only immediate speed-up I can see is that you are running set() more than you need to:

```
    for userid in Scorelife_disct:
    #print userid
    for life_disct in User_life_disct:

        u1= set(Scorelife_disct[userid])
        u2= set(User_life_disct[life_disct])
        # multiply by 1.0 so that the results aren't rounded to nearest int()
        k1=len(u1&u2) * 1.0 /len(u1|u2)
        #print life_disct
        #print k1

        d[userid][life_disct] = k1
        print d
```

Beyond this, you may want to look at a different datastructure to represent your data and optimize it for the most common operations.